# lamp stack localhost using vagrant - not getting any error messages in var/log for system.log or exception.log

Tags: php, magento, exception, logging

It's a magento 12 ee build... I went into some core code and purposely changed a method for log exception purposes to see if i would throw and error. It broke my store (like i suspected) and i got the error message on the front end but it's not writing to my log.

```
System => Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64
Build Date => Apr 17 2015 15:09:58
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini,
```

I just finished checking the permissions on the log folder and it's set to 755.

It's turned on = yes in system preferences of the admin panel.

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '12',
            'revision'  => '0',
            'patch'     => '2',
```

Any ideas?

```
File: `log/'
  Size: 238         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 8192   directory
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 13844008    Links: 7
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  502/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (   20/ dialout)
Access: 2016-03-12 00:55:11.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2016-02-17 22:01:01.000000000 +0000
Change: 2016-03-12 00:48:17.000000000 +0000
 Birth: -



vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/var$ echo $UID
1000
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/var$ id -u <username>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/var$ id -u
1000
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/var$
```

Comment: Who is the owner of the log folder? 755 will only work if the web server user is the owner, which you can do using `chown apache:apache var/log` (or swap out apache for the web user name).

Comment: I got UID 502 / unknown. I suspect this is the problem. How do i fix it and does this seem like it would be causing the problem? My stat command is eddited in my original question above. Please have a look and help me out if you have time.   @MattO

Comment: Uid 502 is your host's login uid. How your site is running? inside vagrant or outside?